# Explicit value and IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a really basic web application and I've created a simple table to store customer data:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTbl] (
    [customerID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [firstName]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [lastName]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [homeTel]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [mobTel]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [passengerCount] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [email]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([customerID] ASC)
);
```

During debug I am getting an error when trying to update entries. Inner exception shows:

`{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CustomerTbl' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}`

I can't understand why this is happening because I am not trying to explicitly write any value to the identity column (`customerID`).

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (FlightDBEntities3 CustData = new FlightDBEntities3())
                {
                    CustData.CustomerTbls.Add( 
                        new CustomerTbl()      
                        {
                            firstName = newApp.FirstName,
                            lastName = newApp.LastName,
                            homeTel = newApp.HomeTel,
                            mobTel = newApp.MobileTel,
                            email = newApp.EmailAdd,
                            passengerCount = newApp.NumberOfPassengers,
                        });
                    CustData.SaveChanges();
```

Should I turn just set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON`? Or is there something here that I am completely missing? At the moment I am totally confused.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your `customerID` field set as an identity column in your entity model?  Are you using code-first or database-first?

Comment: Code-first or database-first?  Meaning are you generating a database from your entity model or generating an entity model from your database?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am generating the entity model from my database. :)

Comment: Check the attributes on the corresponding property in your model, most likely it is not set to be generated by the database.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, you were absolutely right. I went through the entity model attributes and `StoreGeneratedPattern` was set to `None`, I changed it to `Identity`, refreshed and now everything runs as expected. Should this not be done automatically if I am generating my model from database, though?